# How to find the center of the screen in any resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

How to find the center of the screen in any resolution ?

I want my program to appear in the middle of the screen -10 (in the y axis).

(my program is not in max size)

I work with C# in WinForm.

Comment: What you need is [`Screen.WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You could set the [`StartPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) property of your main WinForm to `CenterScreen`. Then if you want it to appear somehow on a different position relative to this screen center, you can play with the [`Top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top.aspx) and [`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left.aspx) properties to add or subtract the required number of pixels.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with @DarinDimitrov's suggestion, however... if you need to know the screen bounds:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

or, taking into account the task bar:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```

...or some variant

Comment: this could be problematic if there are two or more screens with different resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
private void center_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Position the Form on The screen taking in account
the resolution
//
Rectangle screenRect = Screen.GetBounds(Bounds);
// get the Screen Boundy
ClientSize = new Size((int)(screenRect.Width/2),

(int)(screenRect.Height/2)); // set the size of the form
Location = new
Point(screenRect.Width/2-ClientSize.Width/2,

screenRect.Height/2-ClientSize.Height/2); // Center the Location of
the form.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
var screensize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
var programsize = Bounds;
Location = new Point( (screensize.X-programsize.X)/2,
                                  (screensize.Y-programsize.Y)/2 - 10 );
```

Comment: this could be problematic if there are two or more screens with different resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new Point((this.Width + this.Location.X) / 2 - popupControlContainer1.Width / 2,
          (this.Height + this.Location.Y) / 2 - popupControlContainer1.Height / 2)
```

Hope it helps